# Ng-Change Not firing second time

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

I have the following select:

```
    <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="activity">Activity</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <select id="activity" name="activity" class="inputsvalues" ng-model="activitymodel.deptid" ng-change="getUsers(activitymodel.deptid)" ng-options="activity.DepartmentId as activity.ActivityDescription for activity in activities"></select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The controller code:

```
    $scope.getUsers = function (id) {

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'api/User/GetUsers/' + id,


    }).success(function (data, status, header) {
        $scope.users = data;

    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.status = status + ' ' + headers;
    });

}
```

The problem is that the ng-change function gets fired the first timeI select something. Second time onwards, it doesnt hit the controller. What could be wrong here?

Comment: Not sure what's the issue here, but another option is to put a $watch on activityModel and call getUsers accordingly. Is that work for you?

Comment: Tried that too. Doesn't work.

Comment: I am also having same issue, did you find any solution to your issue ?

Answer (score 1):

This is because.. for your code ng-model is same for each value in drop-down. Make ng-model unique for each option. Use $index to achieve this as one of the solutions.